is this solution correct $\frac {\partial}{\partial x} \int_0^∞ \frac{\sin((x+it)\arctan(t))}{((1+t^2)^{(x+it)/2} (e^{2\pi t} -1))} dt =0 $?
when I was reading about the Riemann zeta function I found out this integral $\ \frac {\partial}{\partial x}  \int_0^∞
​ \frac{\sin((x+iy)\arctan(t))}{((1+t^2)^{(x+iy)/2} (e^{2\pi t} -1))} dt  $
and want to ask if I can write it in the form $ \ \frac {\partial}{\partial x} \int_0^x
​  \frac{\sin((x+iy)\arctan(t))}{((1+t^2)^{(x+iy)/2} (e^{2\pi t} -1))}dt  + \frac {\partial}{\partial x}  \int_x^∞
​ \frac{\sin((x+iy)\arctan(t))}{((1+t^2)^{(x+iy)/2} (e^{2\pi t} -1))}dt  $ and then if we find the partial derivative we will get $ \frac {\sin((x+iy)\arctan(x))}{((1+x^2)^{(x+iy)/2} (e^{2\pi x}-1)} - \frac {\sin((x+iy)\arctan(x))}{((1+x^2)^{(x+iy)/2} (e^{2\pi x}-1)} =0 $ by the use of fundamental theoram of calculus which is if $ F(x) = \int_0^x f(t) dt $ then $F'(x)= f(x)$ and if $ F(x) = \int_x^∞ f(t) dt $ then $F'(x)= -f(x)$ and so this derivative should be equal to zero. Tell me if I am wrong and what did I do wrong.

No, the integrand depends on $x$. You need to use the Leibniz rule of integration.

ok ,thanks for the help
